# Add mootools in Facebook iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, javascript, facebook-iframe

I'm a beginner with Facebook Iframe.

This code works well on my page:

```
<script src="js/mootools-1.2.4-core-yc.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/Bubble.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        window.addEvent('domready', function(){
            var positions_for_demo = ['above', 'below', 'left', 'right'];
            $$('.bubble_me').each(function(item){
                new Bubble(item,{
                    position: positions_for_demo.getRandom()
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

But, doesn't work in the Facebook iframe...

Comment: try using Firebug to see where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access window element on facebook iframe.